# Getting cell value after selecting a row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with values MachineGroupID, MachineGroupName, MachineGroupDesc and so on..

I have a delete command in the gridview, when I clicked is supposed to delete the selected row.

Now i have a code which tells me which row is selected.

```
 protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
        string machineID = (String)GridView1.SelectedValue;
        if (row != null)
        {
            LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)sender;

            // Get reference to the row that hold the button
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)LinkButton1.NamingContainer;

            // Get row index from the row
            int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
            string str = rowIndex.ToString();
            //string str = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            RemoveData(str); //call the delete method
       }
 }
```

I want to get the MachineGroupID present in the row so that i can pass that value and delete the record from the database and the gridview?

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE you don't need to put Blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS.........

```
((Label)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("lblID")).Text
```

OR best is RowCommand

```
protected void grdCountry_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    grd.DataKeys[0] // this will return the MachineGroupID
}
```

Comment: I am astonished, after acceptance, why someone has downvoted and not write the reason as well?

Comment: @MuhammadAkhtar how does this work if your id is a  guid

Answer (score 0):

GridView has a [SelectedDataKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selecteddatakey.aspx) property that will give you what you want (make sure that [DataKeyNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx) property of the GridView is set to MachineGroupID)

Answer (score 0):

Set **MachineGroupID** as **DataKeyName** for the grid as `DataKeyName="MachineGroupID"`  and get it by

`GridView1.DataKeys[rowIndex].ToString()` as per your code.

Another way is set the MachineGroupID value to a hiddenfield in Gridview Itemtemplate
and write the following code in codebehind in LinkButton1_Click event :

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
string machineID = (String)GridView1.SelectedValue;
if (row != null)
{
LinkButton LinkButton1 = (LinkButton)sender;
// Get reference to the row that hold the button
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)LinkButton1.NamingContainer;
HiddenField hdn=(HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("hdn");
// get the value of MachineGroupID for the row.
string mcgID= hdn.value;

//--------- Write delete code here-------//
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this
- here is one

I have an image button for deleting but you can use the linkbutton here

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.gif" ID="btnDelete" OnClientClick='return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this item?")' runat="server" OnCommand="DeleteRecord" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("MachineGroupId") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And code:

```
protected void DeleteRecord(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    Guid id = new Guid((string)e.CommandArgument);
    if (RemoveData(id))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: this is good... and i get the value of the machineGroupID in the e.CommandArgument.. but it gives an error when passing it to Guid id..
The error msg is "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)."
Is there a way to just give the string or int value to the id...??

Comment: Yeah, it was just an example.  You don't have to use Guid unless your ID is a Guid.  If it's supposed to be an int use int.Parse(), if its supposed to be a string just cast it (string)